# Limiting the scope of lookaround

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm using regex engine in R and I want to ask regex to lookaround an specific word no more than 3-8 words. how can I do it?

if you need more detail, I'm trying to extract the degree (Mild/Moderate/Severe) of an specific type of heart dysfunction (systolic dysfunction) from a huge number of echo reports. each heart has 2 ventricles, what I want to extract is the systolic dysfunction of the **left ventricle(lv)** and not the right ventricle(rv)

so yes to: "enlarged lv chamber with some degree of **mild to moderate** systolic dysfunction"
and no to: "enlarged rv chamber with some degree of mild to moderate systolic dysfunction"

in echo reports both rv and lv dysfunctions are discussed, so I naturally

would want to use lookarounds to exclude cases where there is an "rv" somewhere with a range of 3-8 words around the for example "mild systolic dysfunction"

I tried lookbehind like this

```
(?<!rv(\\s+\\w+\\s+){3,8})
```

but I get the following error:

"Look-Behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length"

P.S:
I'm using stringr

the code I used is like this:

```
lv_systolic_dysfunction <- "(?i)(?<!rv(\\s+\\w+\\s+){3,8}))\\b(?!lv\\b)((?:\\w+\\s+to\\s+)?\\w+)\\b(?=(?:\\s+lv)?\\s+s[yi]stolic\\s+d[yi]sfunction)"
```

Comment: Can you please provide the exact pattern that does not work with the lookbehind?

Comment: I am not sure what the exact pattern you have but you are probably after https://regex101.com/r/UO4UBA/2

Comment: Hi Wiktor, It doesn't seem to work, I'll still receive the same error:
`lv_systolic_dysfunction <- "(?<!\\brv(?:\\s+\\w+){3,5}\\s+)mild to moderate"

df <- tibble(test = c("normal rv with mild to moderate systolic dysfunction")

str_view_all(df$test, lv_systolic_dysfunction)`

Comment: Sure, you did not try MY regex.

Comment: Oh I see where the problem was, now. those `+` were the issue of "bounded maximum length". Thanks Wiktor

Comment: Right, I expanded the explanation in the answer.

Comment: Also, see this [YT regex quickie of mine](https://youtu.be/OXUpNCHusoA?t=218).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the lookbehind patterns are of "bounded maximum length" by using only the limiting quantifiers in the lookbehind as `+` quantifier matches *one or more* occurrences. While it restricts the lower bound (at 1) it does not restrict the upper bound.

See a [sample R demo](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- tibble(test = c("normal rv with mild to moderate systolic dysfunction"))
lv_systolic_dysfunction <- "(?<!\\brv(?:\\s{1,100}\\w{1,100}){3,5}\\s{1,100})\\bmild to moderate\\b"
str_view_all(df$test, lv_systolic_dysfunction)
```

See [what this regex means here](https://regex101.com/r/UO4UBA/3). `\s{1,100}` matches one to one hundred whitespaces and `\w{1,100}` matches 1 to 100 word characters, this is what is meant by "bounded", capped from below and above. The numbers are arbitrary, just follow the common sense *and* your data when choosing them. It is not likely to have more than 2 spaces in between words in normal texts (I set 100 here just as an extreme example). It is quite sufficient for a word pattern to allow 100 chars. Adjust as you see fit.

Output:

[image]

See a [YT demo of this *constrained-width lookbehind*](https://youtu.be/OXUpNCHusoA?t=218) feature in ICU regex flavor that is used in R `stringr` regex functions.

Comment: thanks I now I get what was the source of the error, but this code should have not included the "mild to moderate" as `rv` was around

Comment: @KasraMehdizadeh It is due to the `{3,5}` quantifier that means that `rv` must be followed with at least 3 whitespace-separated words. If you want to fail the match if there are *zero* to five words between `rv` and `mild to moderate`, then replace `{3,5}` with `{0,5}`.